# rails add ordered, index or full to speed up query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3

So, my rails code generates a huge join query which starts as following:

```
SELECT "CREDITRSP"."ML_TRAN_ID"       AS t0_r0,
...
...
...
```

I noticed that this takes about 5 minutes when i run this in sql developer.

The following alternates were tried which returned results within 3-10 secs:

```
 1.SELECT /*+ FULL("CREDITRSP") */ "CREDITRSP"."ML_TRAN_ID" AS t0_r0,
    ...
    ...


2. SELECT /*+ INDEX("CREDITRSP" IDX2_CREDITRSP) */ "CREDITRSP"."ML_TRAN_ID" AS t0_r0, 
...
...



3. SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ "CREDITRSP"."ML_TRAN_ID" AS t0_r0, 
...
...
```

can either of the above 3 options be implemented in rails?

NOTE: I do not have control to modify, update, table schema migration. This application has only read-only access to those tables.

this is part of the existing model code.

```
class Search

  def search_by_date_range
    get_transactions(FILTER_TO_SEARCH[self.filter])
  end

  FILTER_TO_SEARCH = {
    Filter::AllTran => {
      :filter => "all_tran.between_dates(self.start_date, self.end_date)",
      :models => [
        "credit_responses"
      ]
    }
  }


  def get_transactions(search_hash={})
    if (filter = search_hash[:filter])
      trans = []
      search_hash[:models].each do |m|
        trans += eval("Terminal.#{m}.#{filter}")
      end
      [trans, nil]
    else
      [false, "Incorrect Filter"]
    end
  end


class Terminal < Tv2g::Base
  self.table_name = "terminal"


  has_many :credit_responses
end
```

I am using rails 3 and 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.4.2' gem.

EDIT:

This is how my scope looks for the specific model:

```
class CreditResponse 
  self.table_name = "creditrsp"
  has_one :transaction_code, :through => :credit_request


  default_scope includes(:credit_request, :transaction_code)
```

Comment: If you use `includes` when you generate that query that takes so long, try to replace `includes` with `preload`. The result will be the same but preload will avoid that big, ugly join.

Comment: Thanks.adding preload didn't make any difference though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modifying the rails code to specify a select statement?

```
blah.blah.select('/*+ FULL("CREDITRSP") */ "CREDITRSP"."ML_TRAN_ID" AS t0_r0, ...').blah.blah
```

Comment: it's a 100 line query. I was hoping rails would provide a way to plugin just the full, index or ordered part.

Comment: Hmmm, well you'd just include the SELECT clause in there, if that helps.

Comment: Aldridge. I edited my question with the default scope. How would I add the hint to that?

Comment: the get_transactions method above generates a query which in turn calls Terminal model and which in turn calls credit_responses. It's a convoluted legacy code.